# Marking table, row and cell as DIV iText

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a PDF using iText 5.5.6.
I wanted to tag table, row and cell as a DIV.
I have written the following code but only the table gets marked as a DIV and not the row and cell.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setRunDirection(PdfAWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
table.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
table.setWidthPercentage(80);
table.setWidths(new float[] { 0.8f, 1.2f });
table.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_LEFT);
table.setSpacingBefore(10);
table.setSpacingAfter(15);
Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("Name:", font12);
Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("FirstName LastName", font12);
Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph("DOB: ", font12);
Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph("00-00-0000", font12);
PdfPCell cellp3 = new PdfPCell(p3);
cellp3.setBorder(0);
PdfPCell cellp4 = new PdfPCell(p4);
cellp4.setBorder(0);
cellp3.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
cellp4.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
table.addCell(cellp3);
table.addCell(cellp4);
PdfPCell cellp5 = new PdfPCell(p5);
cellp5.setBorder(0);
PdfPCell cellp6 = new PdfPCell(p6);
cellp6.setBorder(0);
cellp5.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
cellp6.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
table.addCell(cellp5);
table.addCell(cellp6);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie in setAccessibleAttribute() key would be PdfName.DIV and what would be the value? new PdfString()

Comment: Please disregard my comment. I've checked the iText code and I was wrong. Changing a `PdfPTable`'s semantic meaning isn't trivial...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie so, how do i get around this?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm sure that somebody at iText Support knows (that is: if it's possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I test your code the table and all the cells are tagged as DIV. The rows are indeed not.

In iText the classes `PdfPTable`, `PdfPRow` and `PdfPCell` are responsible for table functionality. `PdfPRow` is typically only used in the iText implementation internally, because a `PdfPTable` instance accepts `PdfPCell`s directly.

But you are able to retrieve the table rows to set their role. After you have added all the cells to the table, do this:

```
for (PdfPRow row : table.getRows())
    row.setRole(PdfName.DIV);
```